# setting up a digest http request with a java library

Tags: java, curl, http-headers, digest, digest-authentication

So I am trying to connect to a database (The owners of the server outsource the set up work and don't know details about it) and have a username and password. When I try connecting with curl in the most basic fashion I get denied.

curl --user "Username:password" http://test.com

When I add the --digest flag, it works. So a working curl request looks like this:

curl --digest --user "Username:password" http://test.com

Now the problem is that I need to code this up in java and don't really understand what the --digest flag is doing. I know about digest authentication and the algorithm, but that is something that I do not want to implement nor do I think I need too (based on the fact curl has a trivial flag for this I expect there to be some similar work around in java). Does anyone know a simpler way to do this? Is there just some header I can set that does this? Essentially I want to know the --digest flag from curl's equivalent in java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/user-docs.html) library supports various authentication schemes, but it won't be as straightforward as setting a --digest flag.

Take a look at the relevant documentation here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

A concrete example for preemptive digest authentication here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveDigestAuthentication.java

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this has to do with a database, but --digest turns on Digest authentication. Without it you are using Basic authentication.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--digest

Here's the canonical reference for what those both mean, I'll look to see if I can find something a little more reader friendly and add it if I do.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617

This seems a little easer to... well... --digest :)

http://frontier.userland.com/stories/storyReader$2159

And I also reccomend Apache HTTP client for doing http requests from java, though I'm not sure from your question intro where you mention databases if that's actually what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. Database was a bad choice of words. I am trying to connect to a server that has a database on it.